# RHEL5 sendmail error: NOQUEUE: SYSERR(nobody): can not write to queue directory /var/spool/clientmqueue/

Tags: redhat, sendmail

On my RHEL5 systems, sendmail stopped working after I installed an update.  The new version is sendmail-8.13.8-10.el5_11.  I got errors like this in the logs:

```
NOQUEUE: SYSERR(nobody): can not write to queue directory /var/spool/clientmqueue/
```

and like this when I tried to mail from the command line:

```
WARNING: RunAsUser for MSP ignored, check group ids (egid=53, want=51)
can not write to queue directory /var/spool/clientmqueue/ (RunAsGid=0, required=53): Permission denied
```

It worked (for years) until the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UID and GID for the smmsp user have to be 51/51.  My system was set to use 53/53.   Why, I don't know, silly.

To fix, I had to:

- change uid/gid in /etc/passwd & /etc/group.  Delete old unused "ftp" group 51.
- chgrp smmsp /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail
- chmod g+s /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail
- chgrp smmsp /var/spool/clientmqueue
- restart sendmail

[Redhat also says](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/470663) (paywall, sorry) that you have to have "mailnull" user set to uid/gid 47.  That was already the case for me.  It also warns about having duplicate uid/gid numbers, make sure that there's no other group or user 51.